# Connecting mstsc using script to login and logoff the server

Tags: windows, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, remote-desktop, mstsc

My goal is to login to a machine and logoff from the machine through script.
I am able to connect to machine using the below command

```
$server = "Machine"
$user = "domain\myid"
$Password = "password"
cmdkey /generic:TERMSRV/$server /user:$user /pass:$Password
mstsc /v:$Server
```

Here i get the confirmation prompt for login. I want to bypass this as well and also i need to logoff immediately after login. Is there a way to pass the argument to logoff?

Comment: For first problem remore `TERMSRV/`. For second one you need a mix of `QWINSTA` and `LOGOFF` command.

Comment: Please take a step back and describe the actual problem you're trying to solve instead of what you perceive as the solution.

Comment: during outages.. Most of the server get rebooted and face multiple issues like machine going out of domain, NIC card going to hung state... So we are trying to test the RDP to the multiple machines. I am planning to use script to login to server and logoff the server from my local machine..

Comment: Using something like `Get-WmiObject -Computer $Server -Class Win32_Service` is probably a better approach. Also, you should investigate and fix the issues you describe. They're not normal behavior, even after an unclean shutdown.